# How to add a varying number of Clients to the List along with Date, for 30 days, two different Clients for each date without repeating code?

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, if-statement

I have a code like this:

```
const int IterationsPerDay = 2;
DateTimeOffset currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
int offset = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i += IterationsPerDay)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < IterationsPerDay; j++)
    {
        int iterationIndex = i + j;
            if (iterationIndex < clientsList.Count)
            {
                Client _client = new Client();
        _client.Name = clientsList[iterationIndex].ClientName;
        _client.Date = currentDate.AddDays(offset);
        DatingList.Add(_client);
            } else
            if (iterationIndex >= clientsList.Count && iterationIndex < 2 * clientsList.Count)
            {
                Client _client = new Client();
        _client.Name = clientsList[iterationIndex - clientsList.Count].ClientName;
        _client.Date = currentDate.AddDays(offset);
        DatingList.Add(_client);
            } else
    if (iterationIndex >= 2 * clientsList.Count && iterationIndex < 3 * clientsList.Count)
    {
        Client _client = new Client();
        _client.Name = clientsList[iterationIndex - (2 * clientsList.Count)].ClientName;
        _client.Date = currentDate.AddDays(offset);
        DatingList.Add(_client);
    } else
    if (...)
    { 
        (...)
    } else
    if (iterationIndex >= 29 * clientList.Count && iterationIndex < 30 * clientsList.Count)
    {
        Client _client = new Client();
        _client.name = clientsList[iterationIndex - (29 * clientsList.Count)].ClientName;
        _client.Date = currentDate.AddDays(offset);
        DatingList.Add(_client);
    }
    offset += 1; 
}
```

Is there better way (and shorter in code as well) to continue adding `_client` to the `DatingList` until total of 30 dates are reached?

As you can see I have

> 30 if/else statements

to ensure that 30 days will be added (just in case there was only 1 _client).

The _client number is not fixed.

There are 2 different _clients for each date.

(The only exception will be `_client.count = 1`, at this point `DatingList` will get same client twice for each date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Extract duplicate code into a helper

```
Client CreateClient(int index, int offset) => new Client
{
    Name = clientsList[index].ClientName,
    Date = currentDate + TimeSpan.FromDays(offset) // prefer operators where available
};
```

and then call it

Comment: but the index changes every time, did you notice this_

Comment: That's why I pass it in.

Comment: But did you notice that the index does not change equally? I calculate it differently on each if else

Comment: so I leave the all if else statements that alter the index, just call the helper from inside?

Comment: @positiveperspective yes. You can probably improve it more, maybe flatten the nested loops, but this is the simplest and least arguable improvement

Comment: ok, at least I don't include all the logic to create new record. I will alter the index for each if else and call the helper

Comment: I would however, further extract `clientsList.Count` into a local

Comment: like int ClientsNo = clientsList.Count; ?

Comment: `var clientCount = clientsList.Count;` would be my preference. Abbreviations don't buy as much here, while type of the variable is entirely obvious. That's a strong personal stylistic preference you may disagree

Comment: ok, I will do the coding now. At least I know there is no faster way to do this

Comment: But do case your identifiers correctly conventionally. That means lower camelcase for locals and parameters, leading underscores may be acceptable on fields but not locals or parameters , while Pascal case should be used for properties and methods and perhaps constants

Comment: from efficiency point of view, does using a helper fasten the calculation?

Comment: What do you mean by faster?

Comment: calculation, when the program runs, will it do it faster?

Comment: @positiveperspective no it's likely to have no effect on performance. It's possible there might be an absolute iota of overhead to it actually but it's so insignificant, and so likely to be optimized by the jit that you would be remiss to return to the duplication

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168757/discussion-between-positive-perspective-and-aluan-haddad).